# How can I add a folder outside of my working directory to the Git repository?

Tags: git

I have the directory structure like this:

```
main
|-- folderA
|-- folderB
      |
      |--- .git
```

Unfortunately, I decided I need to track files in folderA under the same repository as folderB.

Is there other ways to do this than creating symbolic links  in folderB?

Comment: will you consider executing git init on folder A?

Comment: @Jasonw: That obviously does not satisfy the requirement to track them in the *same* repository, right?

Answer (score 5):

`git mv` the contents of folderB (except for the `.git` directory into a subfolder called folderB

```
main
|-- folderA
|-- folderB
      |
      |-- folderB
      |--- .git
```

`mv` folderA to folderB

```
main
|
|-- folderB
      |
      |-- folderA
      |-- folderB
      |--- .git
```

`git add` and `git commit` folderA

rename the top level folderB to temp

```
main
|
|-- temp
      |
      |-- folderA
      |-- folderB
      |--- .git
```

`mv` folderA, folderB, and the .git folder to the top level main

```
main
|
|-- folderA
|-- folderB
|--- .git
|-- temp
```

delete the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make A the main repository which includes B, or if you need some kind of separation which you're not making clear, then you can make A a repository and B a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

If `folderA` and `folderB` are not directly depending on each other, only somehow part of the same project, you could track them as separate branches of the same repository.

Then `git-new-workdir` is a useful tool to have two working directories for the same repository (but with different branches).

Of course, this is only useful for special cases - in the general case you should better use Abizern's advice to move the folders a bit around.